# Modifying .hover() after using .addClass() on the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, jquery-hover

So I'm trying to use the .hover() method that only does something if the element being hovered over, DOES NOT have a particular class. It works fine if I add the class to the element in question in HTML. But say I have a click event that uses .addClass() to add the class using jQuery. The hover() method then ignores the class that's been added. Enough rambling. Here is the code.

```
$('.foo:not(.bar)').hover(function() { 

    someCrap();  //when hovering a over .foo that doesn't also have the class .bar, do someCrap

}

$('.foo').click(function(){

    $(this).addClass('bar'); //after the element .foo gets another class .bar, the hover event written earlier continues to work, WTF

})
```

any idea guys and girls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) only adds events to *elements* that is already created. You need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for also creating events for future *elements*. This means that you need to set an *parent* also. Preferably the *parent* should be as close as possible to the *children* that should have the mouse events, to save performance.

```
$('#parent').on({
    mouseenter : function() {
        "use strict";
        // Do something
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        "use strict";
        // Do something
    }
}, ".foo:not(.bar)");
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this requires jQuery v1.7+, just in case anyone is stuck with an older version. However, if you are on an older version there are alternatives to `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `$(selector).hover(fn);` any elements that match *selector* will have the event bound to them. If you were to add/change/remove something about the selector that later on makes that element no longer match, the event would not care because it was already bound.

There are a couple of ways you can handle this, and it really depends on the volume of JavaScript in your application and the specifics of your use case.

1) You could use *event delegation*, which takes advantage of the way that JavaScript events bubble to allow you to bind an event to a parent element of a particular part of your page and do logic at the time in which the event happens - this is very useful for a couple of reasons. One, imagine you have a table with 100 records and a link with a class of `edit` that should fire a particular JavaScript function when someone clicks on it. If you do `$('a.edit').click(fn);` jQuery will end up binding 100 different events to the individual elements. This can start to make your application struggle in older machines/browsers. Secondly, it makes it so that when things change dynamically (either you added a new row to the table or removed the edit class from a link because you no longer want to allow a particular row to be editable) your event is smart enough to know what is going on and still work. In jQuery, you use the `.on()` function for this. Read up on the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you have earlier versions of jQuery you might have to use `.delegate()` and if you are running some really old jQuery functions you are looking for `.live()`.

2) A simpler approach if your application is relatively small is to simply bind the event to all `.foo` elements and check within the event itself if the element currently has a class of `bar` and proceed if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it would be more like:

```
$( '.foo' ).hover(
 function() { if ( $( this ).has( '.bar' ) ) {} else { // do something } },
 function() { if ( $( this ).has( '.bar' ) ) {} else { // do something } }
);
```